# Non-breaking space entities showing up in company names on the jobs sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In the Stack Overflow careers sidebar, I noticed some `&nbsp` non-breaking space HTML entities in the company name.

[image]

Comment: I noticed the same, but in the location (Amsterdam&nbsp;Zuidoost,&nbsp;Nether&hellip; / relocation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oops, sorry about that. Should be fixed now.

Yesterday I was working on a few optimizations to the jobs sidebar to reduce unnecessary memory allocations, and one of the changes involved changing the rendering code to write directly to the output stream, rather than construct an intermediate string first.

There are two methods that write to output: one that is HTML encoded, and one that isn't. I chose the one that *is* HTML encoded without realizing there was already an HTML encoding step in the pipeline.

Comment: Well, better than the other way around. Which would potentially be really painful.

Comment: This still seems to be occurring (now in the location) - http://i.stack.imgur.com/abcaQ.png

Comment: Damn. Looks like we had a regression. Investigating